# Converting pandas dataframe to custom JSON format (then to JS object)

Tags: javascript, python, json, pandas, parallel-coordinates

I would like to plot the result of certain analysis using a parallel coordinates chart. Having found a brilliant example made using protovis http://mbostock.github.io/protovis/ex/cars.html and I am trying to re-arrange my data to replicate the structure of the data file as per the example (`cars.js`).
Hence, my `dataframe` structure:

```
                    north   ch  wwr  ach  tmin  tmax  B1_EMS_DH26
Job_ID                                                           
EP_P1203_000000000    0.0  2.5   40  4.0    24    25       1272.2
EP_P1203_000000001    0.0  2.5   40  4.0    24    26       1401.9
EP_P1203_000000002    0.0  2.5   40  4.0    24    27       1642.3
```

should be converted into the following:

```
var results = [{
    name: "EP_P1203_000000000",
    north: 0.0,
    ch: 2.5,
    wwr: 40,
    ach: 4.0,
    tmin: 24,
    tmax: 25,
    origin: 1272.2
  },
  {
    name: "EP_P1203_000000001",
    north: 0.0,
    ch: 2.5,
    wwr: 40,
    ach: 4.0,
    tmin: 24,
    tmax: 26,
    origin: 1401.9
  },
  {
    name: "EP_P1203_000000002",
    north: 0.0,
    ch: 2.5,
    wwr: 40,
    ach: 4.0,
    tmin: 24,
    tmax: 27,
    origin: 1272.3
  },
  {
    name: "EP_P1203_000000003",
    north: 0.0,
    ch: 2.5,
    wwr: 40,
    ach: 4.0,
    tmin: 24,
    tmax: 28,
    origin: 1642.3
  },
];
```

Other than the replacement of my column `B1_EMS_DH26` into `origin` (which seems to be used by the chart to set line colours), I would like not having to slice rows and replacing symbols manually.

Using the `dataframe.to_json` command returns one line:

```
{
  "EP_P1203_000000000": {
    "north": 0.0,
    "ch": 2.5,
    "wwr": 40,
    "ach": 4.0,
    "tmin": 24,
    "tmax": 25,
    "B1_EMS_DH26": 1272.2
  },
  "EP_P1203_000000001": {
    "north": 0.0,
    "ch": 2.5,
    "wwr": 40,
    "ach": 4.0,
    "tmin": 24,
    "tmax": 26,
    "B1_EMS_DH26": 1401.9
  },
  "EP_P1203_000000002": {
    "north": 0.0,
    "ch": 2.5,
    "wwr": 40,
    "ach": 4.0,
    "tmin": 24,
    "tmax": 27,
    "B1_EMS_DH26": 1642.3
  }
}
```

which is still not quite right.
How do you suggest to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DataFrame (for recreation-purposes):

```
df= pd.DataFrame(
    {'north': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
     'B1_EMS_DH26': [1272.2, 1401.9, 1642.3],
     'tmax': [25, 26, 27],
     'wwr': [40, 40, 40],
     'ch': [2.5, 2.5, 2.5],
     'tmin': [24, 24, 24],
     'ach': [4.0, 4.0, 4.0]
     },
    index=['EP_P1203_000000000', 'EP_P1203_000000001', 'EP_P1203_000000002'],
    columns=['north', 'ch', 'wwr', 'ach', 'tmin', 'tmax', 'B1_EMS_DH26'])
```

This is probably the worst possible way to do this but it works (I think):

```
import re
import json

with open('whatever.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write('var results = [\n')
    for k,v in df.drop('B1_EMS_DH26', axis=1).T.to_dict().items():
        f.write("{name:"+json.dumps(k)+", "+re.sub(r'[{"\']', '', json.dumps(v))+',\n')
    f.write('];')
```

Produces:

```
var results = [{
    name: "EP_P1203_000000001",
    ach: 4.0,
    north: 0.0,
    tmax: 26.0,
    tmin: 24.0,
    ch: 2.5,
    wwr: 40.0
  },
  {
    name: "EP_P1203_000000000",
    ach: 4.0,
    north: 0.0,
    tmax: 25.0,
    tmin: 24.0,
    ch: 2.5,
    wwr: 40.0
  },
  {
    name: "EP_P1203_000000002",
    ach: 4.0,
    north: 0.0,
    tmax: 27.0,
    tmin: 24.0,
    ch: 2.5,
    wwr: 40.0
  },
];
```

It will output a file in the structure I think you're looking for. If not, let me know. Horrible hack I know. Someone with advanced json experience no-doubt knows a better way.

Comment: thanks for that, now I just have to take the `'` symbols out

Comment: ok this is probably looking very petty, but the usage of symbols like `'` and `"` appear to be very sensitive for `.js` syntax.
I have tried performing substitutions after your script for appending, but without success. Essentially, I would need `'EP_P1203_000000001'` -> `"EP_P1203_000000001"`, `'EP_P1203_000000002'` -> `"EP_P1203_000000002"` and all other `'` to disappear (i.e. `'ach'` -> `ach`, `'north'` -> `north` ect.)

Comment: I modified my answer. I'm not sure what format you need it in or if you're printing it from a console. I wrote it to file. Also, does the column ordering matter?

Comment: I had come up with this [awful solution](https://codeshare.io/21Yj0n). Yours may be 'the worst possible way' for you, but it is perfect for me! You made this man very happy!